# How to use Swift 5.7 RegexBuilder to find a word after a sentence

Tags: swift, regex, swift5.7, swift-regexbuilder

I get a report from `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` terminal command for all networks services. The returned text is like this:

```
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Ethernet, Device: en0)

(2) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en1)

(3) iPhone USB
(Hardware Port: iPhone USB, Device: en6)

(4) Thunderbolt Bridge
(Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge, Device: bridge0)

(5) VPN (VPN2)
(Hardware Port: L2TP, Device: )
```

I'm trying to find device for Wi-Fi (`en1`) with RegexBuilder

```swift
        let search = Regex {
            "Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: "
            Capture {
                OneOrMore(.word)
            }
        }

        if let result = try? search.wholeMatch(in: info) {
            print("Device: \(result.1)")
        }
```

This only works if the `Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device:`  string is at the beginning of the text. If there are one or more characters before the above sentence the result would be `nil`

I've tried with this syntax and the result was the same (`nil`)

```swift
        let search = /Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: (\w+)/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `.wholeMatch` with `.firstMatch`.

As the name suggests `.wholeMatch` affects the **whole** string corresponding to a pattern literal with leading "^" and trailing "$"